# How do I use xupload for multiple uploads?

Tags: php, yii, yii-xupload

I want to use xupload in a form. There are three files that must be uploaded (for example, the file ID card, TIN files, and files the certificate). The file name is stored in a database with a table name identity. Can you please tell me how to use xupload for multiple uploads?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can upload:

```
<?php
   $this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
                'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload"),
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'file',
                'multiple' => true,
));
?>
```

For more details, refer to [the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/).